# Fabry-Pérot-Interferometer: What Reflectivity

Tags: optics, interference, interferometry

Apologizing for that narrow question, but considering such interferometer with mirrors characterized by Reflectivity $R$ and reflection coefficients $r = \sqrt{R}$, where $R$ describes the amount of Intensity that the mirrors are reflecting and $r$ the amplitude ratio of reflected wave and incident wave. Now dealing with a Fabry-Pérot-Interferometer, it's of interest to calculate the ratio between the electric field vector $E_{out}$ coming out and the field vector $E_{in}$ that was coming in: $E_{out}/E_{in}$. Further this can be converted to intensity: $I_{out}/ I_{in} = (E_{out}/E_{in})^2$.

But isn't that the same as $R = r^2$? I'm just wondering what's the difference between those 2 relations. The one ($R, r$) is qualifying the ratio of a single ray going in and and being reflected and the other one ($I_{out}/I_{in}, E_{out}/E_{in}$) does account for multiple reflections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electric field out will consist of a reflected field plus that transmitted from within the interferometer. So no, $(E_{\rm out}/E_{\rm in})^2$ will not in general be $r^2$, where $r$ is a property of one of the mirrors.